# Jquery :select till nth td of nth row

Tags: jquery

I want to change the background color of all the rows of a table but only till 4th `td` of every row.

Below is the code I am using:

```js
var rowCount = $('#t tr').length;
$('#t > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('td').eq(i).css("background", "#ff0000");
  }
});
```

Here `t` is the `id` of the table. The result I am getting is that only first row is getting coloured.

[image]

how can we handle rowspan in this scenario?

here is my html code :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="t">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>P1</th>
        <th>P2</th>
        <th>P3</th>
        <th>P4</th>
        <th>P5</th>
        <th>P6</th>
        <th>P7</th>
        <th>P8</th>
        <th>P9</th>
        <th>P10</th>
        <th>P11</th>
        <th>P12</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1">
                        Rebuy IT
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1">
                        Rebuy DC
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
        <td class="col-sm-1">
                        CO DC/IT
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                       Store Inv On Hand
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-1"></td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                       Store Inv In Transit
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-1" rowspan="2">
                       EPR
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                       EPR Shpmts to value
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>

         <td class="col-sm-1">
                       EPR Shpmts to NFS
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>
         <td class="col-sm-1">
                        <input class="col-sm-12"  />
                    </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Do you really need to use jQuery? You can just use CSS.

Comment: i have to take input as n from a text field

Comment: Rajeev, I have identified the problem and answered. Please check. :)

Comment: this is the code i have written on click of button

Comment: Yes, that's right. Check out my answer as well.

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar I've edited my answer to account for your `rowspan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the loop by using jQuery's **[`:lt(n)` selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)**:

> **:lt() Selector**
>
> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```js
var n = 3;
$("tr").find("td:lt(" + n + ")").css("background-color", "red");
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**EDIT:** Given your edit, in which you include rowspans, you may have to take this one step further and use the loop after-all. Here's a solution that might work for you. It only handles rowspans of 2, though I'll improve it to work for rowspans of any size.

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var n = 5;
    var $row = $(this);
    var $prevRow = $(this).prev("tr");
    var rowspan = $prevRow.find("td[rowspan]").length;
    n = n-rowspan;
    $row.find("td:lt(" + n + ")").css("background-color","red");
});
```

---

**EDIT 2:** With the ability to exclude columns at the beginning...

```
var columnsToHighlight = 5;
var columnsToExclude = 2;

$("tr").each(function() {
    var n = columnsToHighlight;
    var $row = $(this);
    var $prevRow = $(this).prev("tr");
    var rowspan = $prevRow.find("td[rowspan]").length;
    n = n-rowspan;
    var gt = n - (columnsToHighlight-(columnsToExclude -1));
    $row.find("td:lt(" + n + "):gt(" + gt + ")").css("background-color","red");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help , one last favour what if i always want to leave  starting 2 columns uncoloured

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar Updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `<td>` selector is generic and not from the `<tr>`:

```
var rowCount = $('#t tr').length;
$('#t > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Change here:
    $(this).find('td').eq(i).css("background", "#ff0000");
  }
});
```

Here, the `$(this).find('td')` is the cue. The `<td>` is not looked up as a whole but only inside the current `<tr>`. In your former case, it keeps colouring or painting only the first 4 `<td>`s of the **whole document**.

Taking inspiration from [Santi's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47398843), also you can try avoiding the `for` loop by using the [less than selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

```
$("#t tr").find("td:lt(3)").css("background", "red");
```

Comment: @Santi I definitely took inspiration from your code. I *did* copy the `.css()` part. Yes. I voted you up for the nice explanation and answer you gave.

Comment: @Santi Thanks. I just updated the answer with due credits. Generally I give credits, but forgot this time. Apologies for that. Check out my answer now. :D

Comment: how can i handle rowspan thing here

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar Can you post your HTML? Because, this one does exactly what your original code asks. If there are rowspans, it shouldn't affect. But colspans will need to be handled.

Comment: @Soolie No worries, much appreciated :)